# Why itext7 did not find the form

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, itext

The situation is as follows, I need to programmatically fill a pdf file with data. The file has exposed fields through the program Adobe Acrobat Pro DC. All fields have names in English. But, when I try to get a form field to put a value into it, a RuntimeError occurs because it can't find the field.
Of course the field can be created programmatically and filled in, but I need a more universal method. What if the location of the field changes, etc.

I use Kotlin and iText 7.2.5

[image: PDF File with form]

```
val form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfWriter, true)
val nameField = form.getField("employer_full_name")
nameField.setValue(newDocumentFields.fullName)
```

Comment: Have you checked whether your PDF is a XFA form?

Comment: @mkl that's an Acrobat form, XFA forms cannot be edited in Acrobat.

Comment: @iPDFdev - Ehm... right. ;) EkatarinaEl - Please share the PDF for analysis; also please share the exact error that occurs.

Comment: @iPDFdev, pdf: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1892phrksdbMhRANsMWKzNWFt_m_1aO8r/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The file is for @mkl as he know more about iText

Comment: @Ekatarina One question first, though: I see in your three lines of code `PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfWriter, true)`. Am I right to assume that (in contrast to the naming) `pdfWriter` is not an instance of `PdfWriter` but of `PdfDocument`?

Comment: @mkl, okey, it`s for you :) PDF: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1892phrksdbMhRANsMWKzNWFt_m_1aO8r/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code (ported to Java and with sensible replacements) like this:

```java
try (
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("Т-1.pdf");
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("Т-1-filledIn.pdf");
    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
) {
    PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(document, true);
    PdfFormField nameField = form.getField("employer_full_name");
    nameField.setValue("The employer's full name");
}
```

and it works without issue:
[image: screenshot]

I also use iText 7.2.5.

Thus, I assume your `PdfDocument` called `pdfWriter` is not appropriately created.

Comment: See, before I open a file for editing, I copy it from the assets folder to downliads. I copy it using a read/write buffer of 1024 bits. Could this be the problem? At the same time, if the same copied file from the phone is transferred to the computer, when I open it Adobe Acrobat sees the form and it can be filled.

Comment: Well, all I can say is that apparently the issue is not in the code you show but in some code executed before. Copying may be a problem if done incorrectly. But without more information I cannot tell whether you copy correctly or not.